# Developing web applications without a mouse

Tags: php, emacs, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to find the best way to debug a single page application with lots of ajax and javascript without using a mouse. What I have noticed is that I spend most of my time clicking on the panels of the web application and then reviewing the results in firebug/chrome developer tools. I am used to developing without ever touching the mouse using emacs, but how can I do the same with a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your needs (& possibilities) you might want to look into something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) for automated testing.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the keyboard shortcuts, [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en&ref_topic=25799), or [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/171571?hl=en&ref_topic=25799), depending on your OS. There will be similar references available for the other major browsers.

Firefox is [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#os=linux&browser=fx21).